# how to display retrieved data through cursor in textbox

Tags: android, sqlite

How to display retrieved data  through cursor in text box.. it gives an error
"Cursor Out of bound..."

```
Cursor c=mydb.rawquery("select * from customer where phone='"+editphone.getText().tostring+" ",null);

editname.settext(c.getString(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use,  `c.moveToFirst()` before `c.getString(0);`

```
Cursor c=mydb.rawquery("select * from customer where phone='"+editphone.getText().tostring+" ",null);
if (c.moveToFirst()){
 editname.settext(c.getString(0));
}
```